# How to use google analytics user timings on android

Tags: android, google-analytics

How to use this [1], i dont understand to use loadTime variables. What do i need to use loadTime variables ?

Thank you.

[1] : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/usertimings

Answer (score 1):

As the reference explains, if you want to report or track some time interval in your app, you can use sendTiming API and send the category and time interval to Google analytics site

This will probably help you to know how much time does your app on different devices take to accomplish a particular task.

Comment: Nargis firstly thank you for reply, i understood that need to calculate loadTime variables myself. its right? , i will use only report google service. I had thought about it before. onLoad method gives me loadTime. But probably this is not possible. i will calculate loadTime myself before and then send to google service.. ok thanks